# How to use PassportJS OAuth strategies with React?

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

There are quite a few sources explaining how to integrate PassportJS for the user authentication for you app (using both local and OAuth strategies). Few of them are explained with regard to a ReactJS + REST API type of application.

Currently I've some boilerplate code which pretty much works, however, not in the way I want it to.
My client will `window.location = 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/${href}'` (where 'href' is e.g. 'facebook') whenever the user clicks a button belonging to an OAuth provider.

The problem with this is that this will cause the React app to lose it's state (which I do not want). Simply fetching the endpoint instead doesn't work in my case either since it will not redirect the user to FB to signin.

Comment: Passport is a package for Node (backend) not react... You can look into https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login for google and there are a few more for FB etc...

Comment: @SakoBu please read the question again. Obviously I'm using Node to configure PassportJS, however, in the end the client has to make relevant requests to the server to get the authentication system to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot give you an exact answer because there is no code to work with, but i can say this is what i've done on one of my personal projects using passport-google.

1. I've used a material ui style google login

here is a sample

```
const GoogleLoginButton = () => {
    const classes = useStyles({});

    return (
        <a href={process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL + "/api/v1/users/auth/google"} className={classes.button}>
            <div className={classes.wrapper}>
                <svg className={classes.icon} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 533.5 544.3">
                    <path fill="#4285f4" d="M533.5 278.4c0-18.5-1.5-37.1-4.7-55.3H272.1v104.8h147c-6.1 33.8-25.7 63.7-54.4 82.7v68h87.7c51.5-47.4 81.1-117.4 81.1-200.2z" />
                    <path fill="#34a853" d="M272.1 544.3c73.4 0 135.3-24.1 180.4-65.7l-87.7-68c-24.4 16.6-55.9 26-92.6 26-71 0-131.2-47.9-152.8-112.3H28.9v70.1c46.2 91.9 140.3 149.9 243.2 149.9z" />
                    <path fill="#fbbc04" d="M119.3 324.3c-11.4-33.8-11.4-70.4 0-104.2V150H28.9c-38.6 76.9-38.6 167.5 0 244.4l90.4-70.1z" />
                    <path fill="#ea4335" d="M272.1 107.7c38.8-.6 76.3 14 104.4 40.8l77.7-77.7C405 24.6 339.7-.8 272.1 0 169.2 0 75.1 58 28.9 150l90.4 70.1c21.5-64.5 81.8-112.4 152.8-112.4z" />
                </svg>
            </div>
            <p className={classes.text}>Login with Google</p>
        </a>
    );
};
```

2. Create a node service that checks for the current user. Something along the lines of `req.user` it will show who is logged in.
3. add a listener for the current user call it in `componentDidMount/useEffect`. I have it called on my navbar component, so it calls on every page load it acts as a listener.
4. use redux to pass isAuthenticated props to your components.
5. Use localStore to  persist data. I'm using sagas so ive done something like this

   ```
    export function* getAutoLoginStatus(action) {
     try {
        const login = yield call(api.user.currentUser);
        const token = login.token;

        if (login.user.googleId !== null) {
            localStorage.setItem("googleId", login.user.googleId);
        }
        setAuthToken(token);
        sessionData.setUserLoggedIn(token);
        yield put(actionTypes.getUserSuccess(login));
     } catch (error) {
        localStorage.clear();
        yield put(actionTypes.getUserFailure(error.response.data.message));
     }
    }
   ```

The main thing is using redux, and keeping the data persisted, and upon logout remove localStorage data. Thats the best way i can explain.